# Knockout.js -Getting error - Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "with: function"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

I am working on a neighborhood map project and I am stuck! I am new to knockout.js. I am trying to use data-bind getting this error -

knockout-3.4.1.js:72 Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "with: function (){return filteredItems }"

The snippet of HTML source -

```
section class="main">
          <form class="search" method="post" action="index.html" >
            <input type="text" data-bind="textInput: filter" placeholder="Click here/Type the name of the place">
            <ul data-bind="with: filteredItems">
              <li><span data-bind="text: title, click: $parent.showInfoWindow"></span></li>
            </ul>
         </form>
        </section>
```

and this is my viewModel -

```
function viewModel(markers) {
  var self = this;
  self.filter = ko.observable(''); // this is for the search box, takes value in it and searches for it in the array
  self.items = ko.observableArray(locations); // we have made the array of locations into a ko.observableArray
  // attributed to - http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/04/utility-functions-in-knockoutjs.html , filtering through array
  self.filteredItems = ko.computed(function() {
    var filter = self.filter().toLowerCase();
    if (!filter) {
      return self.items();
    } else {
      return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.items(), function(id) {
        return stringStartsWith(id.name.toLowerCase(), self.filter);
      });
    }

  });

  var stringStartsWith = function (string, startsWith) {
       string = string || "";
       if (startsWith.length > string.length)
           return false;
       return string.substring(0, startsWith.length) === startsWith;
   };
  // populateInfoWindow(self.filteredItems,)


  // this.showInfoWindow = function(place) { // this should show the infowindow if any place on the list is clicked
  //     google.maps.event.trigger(place.marker, 'click');
  // };

}
```

Some lines are commented because I am still working on it. To see the whole project- https://github.com/Krishna-D-Sahoo/frontend-nanodegree-neighborhood-map

Comment: what's `locations` in `self.items = ko.observableArray(locations);` ?

Comment: `locations` is an array that contains name of locations and their coordinates (the lat lng values). I have given the link to my github repo.

Comment: Shouldn't this line: `return stringStartsWith(id.name.toLowerCase(), self.filter);` be `return stringStartsWith(id.name.toLowerCase(), filter);` *(without the `self`)*

Answer (score 3):

The `with` binding creates a new binding context with the provided element. The error is thrown because of a reference to `title` within the `<span>` element, but `filteredItems` does not have a `title` property.

If you want to display a `<li>` element for each element in the `filteredItems` array, you can use a `foreach` binding, like this:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: filteredItems">
  <li><span data-bind="text: title, click: $parent.showInfoWindow"></span></li>
</ul>
```